# Syncing div height during animation state

Tags: html, animation, css

I've got problem with syncing the height with three columns(div-elements). One of the column is the main content container. But I have some animation in the main content container, so I want to sync the height with the other two columns, during and after the animation. The animation is CSS 3 webkit-transition animation. And the animation is not occuring in the column itself, but in the content of the main content container. I have tried with tables and setting the column's div height at 100%. The thing is the column is synced after the animation. I have tried with Jquery too but with no success, same problem there.

Finally I want to clearify. I want them to be synced during animation, not after!

It would be nice of anyone can provide a solution without having to call a function all the time, like syncColumnHeight();//gets the column height of main content container and inserts it on the other two columns.

UPDATE:
the html code beginning with the table element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='leftColumn'></div>//I want this to sync with the height of the mainContentColumn
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id='mainContentColumn'></div>//All the animation is occuring here
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id='rightColumn'></div>//I want this to sync with the height of the mainContentColumn
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some HTML regarding said columns? I'm not entirely sure what the structure looks like.

Comment: So I added the html Code

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult to solve without looking at your CSS, but I'm guessing divs have the column styling, whereas the tds are the ones that need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/weG8P/

So, in code:

```
table td {
  /*Apply column styles such as background-color here*/
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```